# how to retrieve Data from Intent ??

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I just want to show an simple Employee record on next layoutPage/Activity !!

this is my EmpLogin Java File

```
public class EmpLogin extends Activity {

private Button show;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.show);

    show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            EditText no=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getno);

            EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getname);

            EditText sal=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getsalary);

        Intent emp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EmpShow.class);


            emp.putExtra("EmpNO",(no.getText().toString()));

            emp.putExtra("EmpName",(name.getText().toString()));

            emp.putExtra("Sal",(sal.getText().toString()));

            startActivity(emp);
            }
    });

    }
```

}

How to use Retrieve data from the Intent ??? By using getExtra() method ??? or there is simple way ?? this my EmpShow.class file !!

```
public class EmpShow extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.empshow);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Intent show = getIntent();     
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the link !! sry i didnt search it !!

Answer (score 0):

As you passed data inside`intent`, So try to fetch the `intent` which has started your activity using the `getIntent()` method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

If your extra data is represented as strings, then you can use

`intent.getStringExtra(String name)` method.

---

As per your OP's class  and intent. Here is the snipped which can fetch the values from your `intent` against respective variable,

```
public class EmpShow extends Activity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.empshow);
   Intent intent = getIntent();     
   String empNo = intent.getStringExtra("EmpNO");
   String empNname = intent.getStringExtra("EmpName");
   String empSal = intent.getStringExtra("sal");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 First Activity:
 Intent i=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("VAL",value1);
 startActivity(i);
 Second Activity:
 Intent getI=getIntent();
 String a =getI.getStringExtra("VAL");
```