# Q: Android Dev - Single Background Timer in Service plus Action After

Tags: java, android, android-service

**Hello**,

I've done some research, but to no avail. Also my previous question didn't work as planned.

So here is exactly what I want to do:

**1.)** On my `MainActivity`, the User enters a Numerical value in an `EditText`.

**2.)** When they press an "OK" Button, it starts a Service to run a Timer for how long they entered.

**3.)** When the the Timer time runs out, the Service completes some additional Actions.

Questions:

**1.)** Can I simply use the `Button` to start the Service via an `Intent`, then in the Service put the code?

**1b.)** Can't figure out exactly how to get the User input from the `EditText`, from within Service.

**2.)** Can I run the "additional Actions" when the Timer runs out from WITHIN the Service?

**2b.)** Or, when the Timer is up, do I need to fire a `BroadcastReceiver` to complete the Actions?

**3.)** Do I need to add anything special such as Intent-Filters in my Manifest?

Basically, I'm having trouble figuring out what code goes where.

Currently I'm using a combination of Alarm Manager, `PendingIntent`, and `Intent`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been trying to do this correctly for nearly a month.

I may be somewhat new to programming Android, but I'm eager to learn, so thank you in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


public void timerButtonClick(View view) {


    EditText timerValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
    assert timerValue != null;
    int timerInt = Integer.parseInt(timerValue.getText().toString());


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


    Intent timerIntent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);

    PendingIntent timerPendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getService(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, timerIntent, 0);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (timerInt * 1000), timerPendingIntent);


    finish();


}


}
```

NOTE:  Keep in mind, I'm trying to put the Timer INSIDE my Service, NOT in my Main Activity.. So I assume much of this Code needs to be moved to my Service. But again, not sure exactly how to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: 1b) Pass  user input from the `EditText` as intent extra at `startService`

Answer (score 0):

**1.)** Yes you can ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411499/start-a-service-on-onclick)).

**1b.)** No you can not. Service has no UI interactions at all, but you can create an activity for "after actions". (Edit: But You can pass `EditText` data from `MainActivity` to `Service` using `Intent Extras`) ([see starting activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service).)

**2.)** You can do almost anything or "additional Actions" when the Timer runs out from within the Service, without UI. ([see services tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm))

**2b.)** No, you dont need that.

**3.)** It depends on your timer logic, intent-filters are only needed when you are receiving any broadcasts. If you write timer logic by simply taking [difference between time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15248918/4856761), there is no need, but if you do it with something like [`ACTION_TICK` logic](https://gist.github.com/talhahasanzia/5676c85bfb45a2b7c251b9af65407d4a) which triggers after each minute, you do need to declare intent filter. ([see declare action tick intent filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209028/time-tick-not-called-when-minute-changes))

You will also need to declare service in `AndroidManifest.xml`. If your java class name is `MyBackgroundService`, simply put this in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service android:name=".MyBackgroundService">
</service>
```

Do ask me if anything remains unclear.

**Update:**

I myself am in learning phase and one thing I learned is to look at the official docs first. There is a class [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) in android, which gives you countdown implementation.

- use `onFinish()` of this class to perform whatever action you want to perform.
- first argument of constructor is how long you want to run countdown, second is how much time you want for `tick()` event to occur.
- start countdown by calling `.start()` method.

**Update:**

For putting extras and start service:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyBackgroundService.class);   
String time = editText.getText().toString();
serviceIntent.putExtra("TIME_INTERVAL", time);

startService(serviceIntent);
```

No need for pending intent. You can start with this:

- Create an activity that has : EditText and a Button.
- Create onClick button listener code, which will first check the numeric input is correct or not (number format, negative value etc.).
- If the input is valid you create an Intent for Service class, add data to intent using intent.putExtra("key","numericValue")
- Start service (calling start service method) with intent.
- In service class [receive data from intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069494/4856761), then do calculation in time difference code.
- In service, start a while loop that will check time difference at each loop, and when desired time is elapsed start an activity that will do your action after.

*Please note that service class has a bit different implementation than activity class.*

If your minimum time difference is in minutes, you can use action tick logic link above to see how you implement a service that can run your logic code every minute. In your case logic is also given in above links (time difference). Also I have provided how you retrieve data from intents.

Please try to dig into some code, then comeback here if you get stuck, I (and we the SO community) will surely help, if you are still stuck, I can only write whole codes on weekends, so you will have to try yourself until then.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I still have a few questions though.

If you dont mind, what are the EXACT codes I would use to put the Extras from the user's input into the Intent (in the MainActivity), and also the code i would use within the Service to retrieve it?


Furthermore, I'm assuming this means I DONT need to use a PendingIntent whatsoever?

Keep in mind, I am simply taking the user's input, and starting the Alarm in the background, and when that alarm is up, perform an action..

In a moment, I will post what I have so far, up in my main Question..

Comment: Accept as answer if it solved your problem, ask if something else is confusing.